# Gstreamer boilerplate code is not compiling

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to build Gstreamer custom plugin. I am referring [this](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/basics/boiler.html?gi-language=c) link.

I followed the instructions given in the website, here are my steps,

1. Cloned the git repo using
   `git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-template.git`
2. Created the boiler plate code using below commands

   ```
   $ cd gst-template/gst-plugin/src
   $ ../tools/make_element MyFilter
   ```
3. I verified that, there are `gstmyfilter.c` and `gstmyfilter.h` files in the `/gst-plugin/src` directory.

After this step I am facing issue as Gstreamer documentation is not very clear about this.
Documentation says,
***"run `meson build` from the parent directory to bootstrap the build environment"***.

I ran `mason build` from topmost directory (where we have `build`, `gst-app`, `gst-plugin` folders and `mason.build` file)
But, I am getting below error.

```
The Meson build system
Version: 0.53.2
Source dir: /home/user6/Documents/gstream_examples/custom_gstreamer_plugin/gst-template
Build dir: /home/user6/Documents/gstream_examples/custom_gstreamer_plugin/gst-template/build
Build type: native build
Project name: gst-template
Project version: 1.19.0.1
C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 9.4.0 "cc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0")
C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.34
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Found pkg-config: /bin/pkg-config (0.29.1)
Dependency gstreamer-1.0 found: NO found 1.16.3 but need: '>=1.19'
Found CMake: /usr/local/bin/cmake (3.20.2)
Run-time dependency gstreamer-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
Looking for a fallback subproject for the dependency gstreamer-1.0

meson.build:11:0: ERROR: Subproject directory not found and gstreamer.wrap file not found

A full log can be found at /home/user6/Documents/gstream_examples/custom_gstreamer_plugin/gst-template/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
```

Is it that, I need to upgrade Gstreamer to 1.19?

And does anyone have better guidelines to build the custom plugin? Gstreamer documentation is so good, except this part!!